# Syntax highlighting suddenly disabled after changing name in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

So this is making me pull my hair out.  I set up a project to make a game of snake in python.  I miss spelled the name of the python file and I wanted to fix it.  I refactored it and suddenly lost all syntax highlighting and code hints/autocomplete.  It's as if it is being treated as a .txt file.  Yet I can still run it (by invoking it in the terminal with `python3 snake.py`) so it's a valid python file.

There was a previous question about this on SO, but that answer doesn't apply.  In that scenario, the user had somehow gotten the name of his project in the ignored files under `file types.`  I don't have anything in there that should not be in there:

`*$py.class;*.hprof;*.pyc;*.pyo;*.rbc;*.yarb;*~;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;.svn;CVS;__pycache__;_svn;vssver.scc;vssver2.scc;`

If I make an entirely new project and give my python file that same exact name, I *still* lose all my syntax highlighting and autocomplete

Is there something else I need to fix?

Comment: Hum... For me, my `Python` type under `File Types` is `*.py` and `*.pyw`. Could you provide an image of your `Settings -> Editor -> File Types` with `Python` section selected?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to reproduce this?

Comment: Most likely this file name is associated with "text" file type, check it in settings as @Sraw suggested above.